# Wait for an ResetEvent to RESET

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

**What I want:** I have a 2 threads, one reading/writing from rs232 the other from reading/writing tcp/ip. When data on RS232 is received it sets an `AutoResetEvent` so the main thread knows (by `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`) when new data is received so it can parse the data and send it to the tcp clients (and vice versa).

**The problem**: I can't be sure when the main thread is completed with its task. When the event is set, the main thread starts to send the data to the TCP Clients, but the RS232 thread immediately tries to read again new data. So it could happen, that while the main thread processes the RxBuffer from the RS232, the RxBuffer could be overwritten with new data.

I could create a new `ManualRegisterEvent` called `onRXdataProcceded` which fires when the main thread is finished, but this doesn't sound like a clean way to solve this problem to me.

**The Question:** How do I make sure, that the main thread is completed with its task on the `RxBuffer`, so the RS232 thread is allowed to reuse the `RxBuffer` to perform a new `Read` operation.

Main Thread:

```
TcpServer TCP = new TcpServer();
RS232Server RS232 = new RS232Server("COM5");

//[...]

ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(TCP.onNewDataRX, OnNewRX, TCP, -1, false);
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(RS232.onNewDataRX, OnNewRX, RS232, -1, false);

//[...]

private static void OnNewRX(object o, bool timedOut)
{
    //Send data from TCP to RS232
    //and from RS232 to TCP
}
```

RS232 read thread:

```
public byte[] RxBuffer;
const BufferSize = 255;

//[...]

while (rs232.IsOpen)
{
    RxLen = rs232.Read(RxBuffer, 0, BufferSize);
    onNewDataRX.Set();
    //And now wait until the main thread has read the buffer
    //so its safe to loop again and overwrite the buffer
    //something like onNewDataRX.WaitNotOne(0);
}
```

Comment: Why have the main thread read directly from the rs232 buffer? Why not have the rs232 thread package that data up, and put it in a (concurrent) queue for the main thread?

Comment: @hatchet I'm coming from native C embedded programming, I usually try to reduce the memory size as much as possible, so I didn't though about your solution. But this is kinda stupid on Windows, I know.. I'm gonna try it that way, thanks :)

Comment: There is a class ConcurrentQueue in .Net you can use.

Comment: I will look at this, thanks!
Could some one please explain to me why I got a downvote?